# Using .join() function on a set incorrectly reorders it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of characters (x) that is ordered as I need it:

```
{'a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e',
 'f',
 'g',
 'h',
 'i',
 'j',
 'k',
 'l',
 'm',
 'n',
 'o',
 'p',
 'q',
 'r',
 's',
 't',
 'u',
 'v',
 'w',
 'x',
 'y',
 'z'}
```

However, when I attempt to convert these back to a string using the .join() function:

```
return ' '.join(x)
```

The characters are being randomly reordered:

```
'c g e w i z n t l a q h p d f v m k b x u r j o y'
```

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: Prior to Python-3.7, sets were not ordered, so it can return the elements in *any* possible order.

Comment: You can use an `OrderedSet` if you want to ensure that set retains its insertion order.

Comment: if you really want sorted order you can use `return ''.join(sorted(x))`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `set` objects are still not ordered

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: ah yes, only dictionaries. It's a bit a pitty. Since a `set` can be seen as a dictionary, but where the values are not that relevant. So one could probably with some templates "reuse" the C++ code of a `PyDict`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, I just use a `dict` now :)

Answer (score 3):

Sets don't "promise" to maintain order, sometimes they do, but they shouldn't be used with a dependency on it. Furthermore, consider using the following:

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Then:

```
return " ".join(alpha)
```

**However**, if you only care about it being in alphabetical and want to use a set you can force it to be sorted before using the join function...

```
return " ".join(sorted(x))
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Sets and dictionaries are unordered (pre Python 3.7). Their exact implementation involves hashtables and can be a little complicated. However, suffice it to say that the order you put elements into the set does *not* determine the order they are stored.

You can use `OrderedDict` or you can convert the set to a list, sort, and go from there.

Comment: `OrderedSet`. There is no such thing built in to python. Similarly a `set` is still not in insertion order in Python3.7 (though dictionaries are).

Comment: I meant OrderedDict.